# In DASH, why is in the coinbase transaction sometimes the first output the masternode reward, and other times the second?

Tags: coinbase-transaction, dash

[Example of the first output being a masternode reward](https://chainz.cryptoid.info/dash/block.dws?852296.htm)
[Example of the first output being a proof-of-work reward](https://chainz.cryptoid.info/dash/block.dws?852294.htm)

What determines the order of the outputs in the generation transaction?

As far as I understand it:

In `src/miner.cpp` in the `CreateNewBlock` function it is determined that the `vout` index for proof-of-work is 0. Line 86-90:

```
CMutableTransaction txNew;
txNew.vin.resize(1);
txNew.vin[0].prevout.SetNull();
txNew.vout.resize(1);
txNew.vout[0].scriptPubKey = scriptPubKeyIn;
```

Later on in the function it calls the `FillBlockPayments` function In `src/masternode-payments.cpp` Line 294:

`FillBlockPayments(txNew, nHeight, blockReward, pblock->txoutMasternode, pblock->voutSuperblock);`

which calls the `FillBlockPayee` function. Line 222:

`mnpayments.FillBlockPayee(txNew, nBlockHeight, blockReward, txoutMasternodeRet);`

There the masternode reward is appended as an additional `vout` to the transaction `txNew`. Line 287-291:

```
// split reward between miner ...
txNew.vout[0].nValue -= masternodePayment;
// ... and masternode
txoutMasternodeRet = CTxOut(masternodePayment, payee);
txNew.vout.push_back(txoutMasternodeRet);
```

Why then, in the generation transaction, is the first output not always the proof-of-work reward?